# How to swap strings in all lines?

Tags: text-editing

Emacs 26.1

I have this text:

```
"ADA-SGD"
"ADT-SGD"
"ADX-SGD"
"AID-SGD"
"AMP-SGD"
"ANT-SGD"
"ARDR-SGD"
"ARK-SGD"
```

I want to swap text in all these lines. The result must be like this:

```
"SGD-ADA"
"SGD-ADT"
"SGD-ADX"
"SGD-AID"
"SGD-AMP"
"SGD-ANT"
"SGD-ARDR"
"SGD-ARK"
```

How I can do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another option: using [Multiple Cursors](https://github.com/magnars/multiple-cursors.el) you can do it with three commands!

Starting with point (the cursor) on the first hyphen `-`:

1. Mark the hyphen with <kbd>Shift right-arrow</kbd> or <kbd>C-space</kbd> <kbd>C-f</kbd>
2. Mark all hyphens with `M-x mc/mark-all-like-this` or <kbd>C-c</kbd> <kbd>C-<</kbd>
3. Transpose words with `M-x transpose-words` or <kbd>M-t</kbd>

Answer (score 6):

I personally think the `query-replace-regexp` solution is better, but just for fun here is another solution with macros:

```
;; Move cursor to start of first line
<f3>      ;; kmacro-start-macro-or-insert-counter
M-f       ;; forward-word
M-t       ;; transpose-words
C-n       ;; next-line
C-a       ;; move-beginning-of-line
<f4>      ;; kmacro-end-or-call-macro
;; Select remaining lines
C-x C-k r ;; apply-macro-to-region-lines
```

Comment: Executing your macro with numeric argument 0 should also work as intended, as going past the last line in a buffer errors out and terminates execution.

Answer (score 5):

You can do it with `C-M-%` (running `query-replace-regexp`): Give it the string `"\([A-Z]+\)-\([A-Z]+\)"` (quotes included) for the text to replace, and `"\2-\1"` for the replacement.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use query-replace-regexp (default key C-M-%) for this.
search pattern would be something like

```
"\(.*\)-\(SGD\)"
```

and the replacement would look like this then

```
"\2-\1"
```

replace-regexp is great for such things, check the emacs wiki for mor information about that
[emacs regexp](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/RegularExpression#regexp)

Answer (score 3):

Regexps are an overkill in this case since emacs has a built-in command `transpose-words` that is bound to `M-t` by default. This command, combined with isearch are enough to solve the problem when linked together with emacs keyboard macros.

https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Basic-Keyboard-Macro.html

Learn to use keyboard macros and you can solve most repetative text editing tasks.

Place the cursor before the first line, start recording the keyboard macro, press `C-s` and `-` to move the cursor to the next hyphen, press `M-t` to transpose the words, stop recording. Then repeat the macro as many times as needed. Alternatively, you can apply the macro to a region of lines.

Comment: See also @0x5453's answer, which likewise used `transpose-words` in a keyboard macro.